# In SAS, how do I connect to a remote Oracle database by specifying the IP address of the Oracle's host?

Tags: oracle, sas

We have two computers, A and B. Computer A (AIX 5.3, not sure about the version) is running the SAS server, and computer B (Win 7) is running an Oracle XE. Both computers see each other in the LAN without any problems.

I have explored many ways to connect to an Oracle database such as the LIBNAME statement and the Pass-Through Facility, but I can't find any way to explicitly say in these declarations the IP address of the Oracle's host.

I am hoping for a solution that doesn't require installing another Oracle in computer A, since we have no admin privileges there. I can't also use ODBC or OLE DB, since these require admin privileges in computer A to configure.

Have I missed anything in my Googling? Or is there another way? Thank you all for your help.

EDIT: I don't mean if it means something, but I found out that there is an Oracle in computer A. I don't have any means of configuring it, though. Same goes for its listener.

Comment: Do you have SAS/ACCESS to ORACLE licensed?

Comment: Yes, sir. All licenses are good.

Comment: Have you tried connecting like:  `proc sql;
   connect to oracle as dbcon
       (user=testuser password=testpass buffsize=100 
        path='\\10.1.15.15\myorapath');
quit;` where myorapath is the path on the oracle server and 10.1.15.15 is your actual server ip address?

Comment: Just tried it, it didn't work. I think we have an Oracle in computer A, but I'm not sure since I've been trying to run LSNRCTL status through PuTTY (I haven't seen the real-life computer A) and the error is command not found, not authorization failure. Anyway, the error message spawned by your script is an "ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified."

Comment: Edit to that: I found an Oracle in computer A. I ran LSNRCTL status, but a lot of "Message XXXX not found; no message file for product=network, facility=TNS".

Comment: This probably belongs on SuperUser.

Comment: @hong-ooi I can't find any SAS syntax clues on SuperUser. All I got was hardware :)

Comment: I think @HongOoi is right, fundamentally; this is more of a server configuration issue than a SAS specific issue.  But I think Bob's answer below is probably right - it's about what I was going to suggest, but I don't have enough familiarity to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use SAS/Access to Oracle on your server "A", that server must have the Oracle networking client software installed and configured.  Normally that is managed by an Oracle administrator on that server.

It can be as simple as adding an entry into the `tnsnames.ora` file on your server that "points" to the Oracle instance running on your Windows machine "B".  The details of what needs to be added should come from your Oracle DBA.

Once you can successfully connect to that Oracle environment from your server "A" (using something like sqlplus or testing with the tnsping command), SAS will use the same connection.

The point is that this does not have anything directly to do with SAS; you must set up the environment first.  However, note that there are certain posit-installation steps that must be performed by your SAS administrator for everything on the SAS side to work.  Double-check with whoever installed SAS on your server to make sure those steps were completed.

Comment: Then the only way for SAS to access the data in the Oracle in "B" is by connecting to it with the Oracle in "A"?

Comment: Depends on what you mean.  For SAS on your computer "A" to connect to the Oracle database running on computer "B", it must use the Oracle client software installed on computer "A".  There does not need to be an actual Oracle database running on computer "A", but the client software must be installed.  It is similar to installing an ODBC driver on your PC.  The driver comes from Oracle and SAS just uses it.